# How to compare times?

Tags: algorithms

i'm looking for an algorithm to compare 2 different time records.
My time format is

```
hour:minute:second:nanosec
```

I tried something like this, but its not working well:
if (hour <= anotherHour) {
            if (min <= anotherMin) {
                if (sec <= anotherSec()) {
                    if (msec <= anotherMsec()) {
                        return -1;
                    } else {
                        return 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    return 1;
                }
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert all times into a common unit, for example seconds, and then you don't need to do nested if statements.

Comment: Your base unit $u$ would be the nanosecond, so $u=n+1000000000(s+60(m+60h))$, where $n$ stands for nanoseconds field, $s$ stands for seconds field, $m$ stands for minutes field, and $h$ stands for hours field. Then compare $u$s.

Comment: @SenexÆgyptiParvi There's no requirement to use nanoseconds as the base unit. You could use hours if you want to. Just have the data be doubles.

Comment: The reason I specified nanoseconds is that the top line of the OP's   own work did so.